# How to retrieve Celery tasks that have not yet started, using Django?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

From reading the [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-reserved-tasks), it looks like I should be able to use the following python code to list tasks on the queue that have not yet been picked up:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
tasks = i.reserved()
```

However, when running this code, the list of tasks is empty, even if there are items waiting in the queue (I have verified they are definitely in the queue using django-admin). The same is true for using the command line equivalent:

```
$ celeryctl inspect reserved
```

So I'm guessing this is not in fact what this command is for? If not, what is the accepted way to retrieve a list of tasks that have not yet started? Do I have to maintain my own list of task IDs in the code in order to query them?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to handle a situation where two tasks are queued which perform a write operation on the same object in the database. If both tasks execute in parallel and task 1 takes longer than task 2, it will overwrite the output from task 2, but I want the output from the most recent task i.e. task 2. So my plan was to cancel any pending tasks that operate on an object each time a new task is added which will write to the same object.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can see pending tasks using `scheduled` instead of `reserved`.

`$ celeryctl inspect scheduled`

Comment: "celeryctl inspect scheduled" only shows ETA and countdown tasks. That leaves out regular tasks, which are the vast majority for most workloads.